# Cannot Compile Class - Illegal Start of Expression

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a class that utilizes three other classes.

```
public class Employee
{
private Name name;
private Address address;
private Date date;
// define data fields

public Employee( String name1, String name2, String street, String city, String state, String zip , int month, int day, int year)
    {
    Name name = new Name( name1 , name2 );
    Address address = new Address( street, city, state, zip);
    Date date = new Date();
    date.setDate( month , day, year );
    }
// constructor

public String GetName1()
    {
    String name1 = name.GetFirstName();
    return name1;
    }
// first name getter

public String GetName2()
    {
    String name2 = name.GetLastName();
    return name2;
    }

public String GetStreetName()
    {
    String street = address.GetStreet();
    return street;
    }
// street getter

public String GetCityName()
    {
    String city = address.GetCity();
    return city;
    }
// street getter

public String GetStateName()
    {
    String state = address.GetState();
    return state;
    }
// street getter

public String GetZipCode()
    {
    String zip = address.GetZip();
    return zip;
    }
// street getter

public String GetDate()
    {
    String time = date.getDateString();
    return time;
    }
}
```

When I attempt to compile it, each method past the first three is met with the same compile error:

```
Employee.java:32: error: illegal start of expression
public String GetStreetName()
^

Employee.java:32: error: ';' expected
public String GetStreetName()
                           ^
```

Looking over the code, I can't identify what could possibly prevent this class from functioning. The other three classes do compile and function without error.

Comment: Does the `Address` class have a `GetStreetName()` method? By the way, Java naming conventions state that method names should start with lower-case letters.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error using this code and dummy classes for `Address` etc, and I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Closing the compiler and trying again failed to reproduce the error.